# using jquery on child frame without loading it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-javascript

is it possible to load and use jquery in the parent iframe page & inside the iframe whithout loading jquery twice, 
meaning to load jquery just once in the page and using it in the ifrmae within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make sure the `<iframe>` isn't loading the jQuery script i.e. `<script src="....">` then you can access the jQuery instance in the parent like so:

```
var $ = window.top.$;
```

Be sure to use the correct context using the second parameter:

```
$('img', document);
```

If this isn't possible you can't "prevent" a script from being downloaded and executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the child frame a reference to the `jQuery` object from the parent frame, but you'd have to be very careful about using it because in various places, `jQuery` uses the `document` object of the context in which it was loaded, which will (of course) be the parent's `document`. In some places you can override that (for instance, when searching for elements via `$()` you can give a context in which to search as a second parameter), but it's likely to be more trouble than it's worth.

But re-loading jQuery shouldn't be an issue. It should come from cache. Granted, there may be an extra HTTP GET with an "unmodified" response, although by using proper cache headers when serving the jQuery file, you could avoid even that. (I haven't checked the cache headers of the various CDNs that host it.)